# Drupal ; TOTP Authentication for authenticated users

Tags: drupal-7, google-authentication, two-factor-authentication

I have enabled the modules Two Factor Authentication and TFA Basic Plugins. I am using TOTP as my validation plugin. I had downloaded the Google Authentication app on my mobile device.

I have successfully done TOTP Authentication on my admin account. However, I have several authenticate user accounts I need to make. How can I set there accounts so that they can do TOTP Authentication?

Currently if I create a user/password for them then go to security, I see the TOTP Authentication screen where I can scan. However, how do I give the user the ability ?

If I provide them user/password but want them to have TOTP setup to there mobile device how do I do that?

Thanks in advance,
Mike

Comment: my answer @ https://drupal.stackexchange.com/a/214865 would more suitable for this question.

Answer (score 0):

You may have come across this by now, but there is a permission "Set up TFA for account" provided by TFA Basic, which you'll want to ensure you set for relevant roles (which may well be simply "authenticated user").

In case you were looking to use the "require TFA" for a role, then any user with that role will be unable to log in all by themselves, and will get an error "Login disallowed. You are required to set up two-factor authentication. Please contact a site administrator".

Therefore, if you wish to enforce TFA, you'll need to do some custom implementation unless you're in a position to walk each user through initial setup (I suspect not). https://www.drupal.org/node/2622030 should provide some pointers for this.

You could consider https://www.drupal.org/project/tfa_rules instead of enforcing TFA: at the least it offers a default rule which encourages those who have not enabled TFA to do so.